# WebRole with Async/Await keyword not running on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-web-roles

I am using the following piece of code to read a file from an http request.

```
var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
streamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
```

I am using .net 4.0.So for the **async/await** keyword I have installed **Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package**.This is working fine on my local machine.But when I try to upload the package to azure,the webrole fails to run.

Comment: "fails to run" doesn't really give us much information. Any errors? Anything in the logs?

Comment: Have you marked these assemblies as "Copy Local" = true?

Comment: @JonSkeet, The following error message is shown when I try to update the azure instance:- "Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation."

Comment: @GauravMantri, Yes, I have tried that. Bud that did not make any difference.

Comment: It sounds like there should be other log entries showing *why* it's recycled a number of times. Look carefully at all the logs available.

Comment: If you have Windows Azure Diagnostics enabled, look into event logs. If the diagnostics are not enabled, I recommend enabling remote desktop on your role, connect via RDP and check event logs on the machine.

Comment: *This works fine on my local machine*:  Are you running this as a website locally or through the Azure Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response everyone. Instead of **Microsoft.Bcl.Async**, I used **AsyncBridge** for the **async/await** keywords and now it works locally as well as on the azure server.

Comment: This is also not supported. Please target .NET 4.5.

Comment: AsyncBridge is used to support async/await for .net 4.0 projects. I used this and hosted my azure package on server. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Neither AsyncBridge nor Microsoft.Bcl.Async rewrite the core ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`, which is required for a correct `async`/`await` solution on that platform. The [blog post I linked to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx) clearly states that the behavior is undefined. So it may work in some simple situations; it will certainly **not** work for all `async` code. Since you're on Azure, upgrading to .NET 4.5 is a really simple option and will move you from "undefined behavior" territory to "fully supported".

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this will not work. You cannot use the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package on ASP.NET (including web roles). This is because ASP.NET [needed some rewriting of some core types in order to support `async`/`await`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx), and you don't get this with the NuGet package.

On ASP.NET, you *must* target .NET 4.5 in order to use `async`/`await`.